# unclosed tags in html ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, tags

i have a description of a product who fill by ckeditor.  i show a part of the description on the page. the problem is that they create a problem.

suppose ckeditor created `<p>blahblah</p>` and i cut the text to the limit code have then logically p tag is not closed. so here is something i can do.

close the tag. are i can get  the text from them and append inside the div i create. well how  i can do that.

Comment: Its getting hard to understand the post. The issue is visible, but what you have tried is not visible. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issues is that you need to display a excerpt of the full description? Is it feasible, in that case, to just strip HTML and just display a certain amount of characters?

Comment: It should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need extract text from html or fix the html you can try using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)